# Pinterest image height

Tags: php, html, css, image, pinterest

```
<div class="pin_image">

   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img width="191" height="auto" class="<?php echo $img_class; ?>" 
                src="<?php echo PricerrTheme_get_first_post_image(get_the_ID(),102,72); ?>" /></a>
</div>
```

How do I make images above to dynamically generate height based on aspect ratio of picture? Width will be 191px. Just like pinterest.

Comment: There is no question here. Kindly edit the question and rephrase to make this comprehensible.

Comment: If you are trying to match Pinterest exactly, I think you'll find their images are 192 pixels wide in the thumbnails in the RSS feeds.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to set height to AUTO from CSS, instead of using the HTML4 tag width property. Using inline styles (which are never a good idea IMO, except for demonstration purposes.), edit your code to look like this:

```
<img src="blah.png" style="width:100px; height:auto;" />
```

Good luck with your project! :)